# Accessing multiple <select>-ed parameters with Perl CGI

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am using the Perl [CGI](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI) module. If I have HTML like this

```
<select multiple name="FILTER_SITE">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

and submit my form I can get something like this in the URL: 
`[..] FILTER_SITE=1&FILTER_SITE=2`

Perl's `my $FILTER_SITE   = $cgi->param('FILTER_SITE');` wil capture only the first instance.

How can I make use of both (in this case)? Hack it and parse the referrer myself and add them to an array is my first idea but it'd be a bit messy, then again I'm hardly versed in CGI.pm or Perl.

With Data::Dumper, interestingly

`print "<pre>".Dumper($cgi->param('FILTER_SITE')) . "</pre>";`

```
$VAR1 = '1';
$VAR2 = '2';
```

Comment: Is `optrion` a typo? Try: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $cgi->param('FILTER_SITE');`

Comment: This isn't something that's hidden in the docs.

Comment: Indeed, the wonders of rapid development..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***NOTE: Current documentation (as of 2020 May 29) says this method could cause a security vulnerability. Please check my answer below.***

The `param` method supplies a single value in scalar context and (potentially) multiple values in list context. Read about it [here](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#FETCHING-THE-VALUE-OR-VALUES-OF-A-SINGLE-NAMED-PARAMETER:).

So if you change your code to, for example

```
my @FILTER_SITE   = $cgi->param('FILTER_SITE');
```

then the array will contain all selected values of the option.

If it suits your code better, you can also write

```
for my $FILTER_SITE ($cgi->param('FILTER_SITE')) {
  :
}
```

Comment: Excellent I trust this will work but really gotta dash and will check back later!

Comment: @Recc: your example with `Data::Dumper` works because a subroutine call puts the parameters in list context. `Dumper` will display the values of every item in the list, as you have seen.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but looks like few things changed since this question was answered. I want to post the latest info on this, especially because the accepted answer is now considered a security vulnerability. [CGI.pm documentation says](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI)

{`Warning - calling param() in list context can lead to vulnerabilities if you do not sanitise user input as it is possible to inject other param keys and values into your code. This is why the multi_param() method exists, to make it clear that a list is being returned, note that param() can still be called in list context and will return a list for back compatibility.`}

It is recommended to use `$cgi->multi_param` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Example of parsing values

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use Encode;

    print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n";

    if($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST") {
      read(STDIN, $querystring, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
     print "<h1>POST</h1>";
    } else {
      print "<h1>GET</h1>";
      $type = "display_form";
      $querystring = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
    }

    print "<p>$querystring</p>";

    if (length ($querystring) > 0){
      @pairs = split(/&/, $querystring);
      foreach $pair (@pairs){
           ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
           $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
           $name =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
           if (exists $in{$name}) {
             $value = "$value,$in{$name}";
           }
           $in{$name} = $value;
      }
    }

   foreach my $val (sort keys %in) {
     print "<p>$val: $in{$val}</p>";
   }
```